# How do I rotate an UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rotation

I used to rotate an image this way:

```
self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.image.transform, 
                                      CGFloat(M_PI))
```

But this code doesn't work for a button:

```
let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI)
```

But I don't know how to assign that rotation to the button. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created a `CABasicAnimation`. You should now add it to a `CALayer`.
Try using this code:

```
button.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: "myAnimationKey");
```

Set a duration this way:

```
let duration = 1.0
rotateAnimation.duration = duration
```

A `UIButton` has a layer Property.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add your animation to the layer of your button.

```
//If you want a duration
rotateAnimation.duration = yourDuration

//You can set a key, but must not.
button.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
```